# Update global NPM packages with linked local package

Tags: npm

I linked a local package globally using `npm link`. Unfortunately when I try to update my globally installed packages it now gives an error:

```
$ npm update -g
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue_type_checker - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'vue_type_checker@*' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

**update** - As a cleaner solution, I wrote [a node script to print only unlinked global npm packages](https://gist.github.com/phette23/d7e5ab84a0924333f6908112866f1199), I'll paste it below. With this script as an executable somewhere on your path (named `npm-lsg-unlinked` in this example), you run `npm-lsg-unlinked | xargs npm update -g` to update all global npm packages without updating linked ones (which is the cause of OP's error).

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const { exec } = require("child_process")

exec('npm ls --global --json', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) throw err

    const deps = JSON.parse(stdout).dependencies
    // dependencies hash looks like:
    // "linked-pkg": { "version": "1.0.0", "resolved": "file:..." },
    // "global-pkg": { "version": "1.0.0" }, ...
    // so we skip any package that has a "resolved" property
    const output = Object.keys(deps).reduce((total, key) => {
        return deps[key].resolved ? total : `${total}${key}\n`
    }, '')

    process.stdout.write(output)
    process.stderr.write(stderr)
})
```

---

I wrote about this on [my similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691622/update-all-global-npm-packages-except-linked-ones)[Update all global npm packages except linked ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691622/update-all-global-npm-packages-except-linked-ones)) but as far as I know, there's no native way in npm's CLI to avoid this. `npm update -g` without an argument tries to update *all* global packages, including the ones symlinked into the global node_modules folder by `npm link`, which will fail if it's a local package you're working on that's not in the npm repository.

I tried to find a work-around using `npm ls -g` and shell tools to filter its output to only the non-linked packages and this was my first try:

```sh
npm ls -g | tail -n+2 | tr -d '├─└ ' | \
    sed -e '/ \-> /d' -e 's|@[0-9.]*||' | xargs npm update -g
```

That takes a list of global npm modules, deletes the useless first line, trims the formatting (characters like "└──"), deletes lines with " -> " in them (these are the linked packages), strips off the version string from the package name, and then pipes the list of global package names to `npm update -g`.

Some of the `sed` regular expressions are not perfect and this command will need updating if `npm` ever changes their output syntax. I also thought about piping `npm ls -g --json` through a [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) filter but I couldn't figure out how to write it given the structure of npm's JSON output.